# Whois shows empty data but domain not free

Tags: whois

I looked whois for `mrs.in` . It isn't free but the **whois** data is almost empty.

Why is so?

[image]

Comment: Availability of domains for your site is on-topic as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

> i was trying to buy it

Just missing from your screenshot above, the "Registrant Email" states "Please contact the Registrar listed above". The only other significant information is the "Registrant Country: CN" (China). My guess is the absence of any registrant information may simply be a form of *domain privacy*, possibly implemented by the Registrar. The domain is certainly registered (as indicated by the presence of the Whois record, expires 2021-05-04) and points to a domain parking service (Bodis).

At the top of the "parked page" it states:

> The domain mrs.in may be for sale. Click here to inquire about this domain.

Clicking the above link takes you to a contact form that supposedly allows you to "send an inquiry to the owner of Mrs.in."

> The owner of Mrs.in has chosen to receive offer inquiries regarding this domain name.

A domain like `mrs.in` has the hallmarks of being a "premium domain" (short, keyword). Although whether this is the intention of the registrant is unclear.

Comment: I do not think there are premium names in `.IN` and privacy may not be possible, the munged whois reply from the registry whois server is just general data protection policy

Answer (score 0):

First, whois is not a tool to check availability of a domain name. It really isn't. Some domains can never appear as registered in whois, yet they will never be available for registration, because they are on reserved lists.

Only registrars have typically an API with the registry to do live availability checks. Hence, you need to go at a given registrar and test the domain there. Or if you are lucky, use the registry RDAP server that has a mode of operation tailored for domain availability checks, but this is still far from being deployed everywhere, and especially in ccTLDs.

Now on your specific example: you got a whois reply! You think it is empty, but it is not!
Just look at:

```
Creation Date: 2019-05-04T20:00:09Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2021-05-04T20:00:09Z
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
```

This clearly shows this domain is registered.

You think it is empty because there is little contact data. This is unfortunately the aftermath of GDPR-level rules and similar where basically personal data of individuals has to be better protected and not published without caution. ICANN (for gTLDs) implemented a temporary specification that just basically makes whois useless as not giving any more any data, and some ccTLDs just followed and do the same, like this one.